# sql server query to replace variables with values recursively

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table `variable` containing variables names and their values, for example :

- var1 = value1
- var2 = value2
- var3 = value3

Another table `expression` contains expressions :

- "a string using #var1# and #var2#"
- "another one with #var3# and #var4# and even #var1#"

and I want to replace the variables present in the table `variable` by their values, so the result should be :

- "a string using value1 and value2"
- "another one with value3 and #var4# and even value1"

Is there a way to do this with a CTE ?

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c1e1e/2/0

Comment: Why would you want to do this recursively?

Comment: Because if you don't do it recursively I don't think there is a way replace several variables in the same line.

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to split the expression into parts with a sequence number?  You could then reassemble the parts like so:  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e0f21/6

Comment: Thank you for your response but I can't change the schema

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This one was a good brainteaser. Here's a recursive CTE approach:

```
--using recursive CTE
with 
    subq (original, corrected, PassNum) as
        (
         select expression.expression as corrected, expression.expression as original, 1 as PassNum from expression
         union all
         select subq.original, cast(replace(subq.corrected, '#' + variable.name + '#', variable.value) as varchar(100)),
         PassNum+1 as PassNum from subq, variable where subq.corrected like '%#' + variable.name + '#%'
         )

update expression set expression.expression=subq.corrected from expression inner join subq on 
expression.expression=subq.original where subq.passnum=(select max(passnum) from subq)
```

It has some annoyances, like the fact that you have to cast the corrected value so it matches the column size (see below for more about this), and the `PassNum` variable, which was the only way I could find to indicate which update was the final one.
The mundane cursor approach is probably easier to debug since it's more straightforward:

```
--using cursor
DECLARE @name VARCHAR(50)  
DECLARE @value VARCHAR(50)

DECLARE loopCursor CURSOR FOR  
SELECT name, value from variable

OPEN loopCursor  
FETCH NEXT FROM loopCursor INTO @name, @value  

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
BEGIN  
       update expression set expression.expression=replace(expression, '#' + @name + '#', @value)
       FETCH NEXT FROM loopCursor INTO @name, @value
END  

CLOSE loopCursor  
DEALLOCATE loopCursor
```

Here's the quote I found about the casting when using a recursive CTE:

> The behavior you are seeing is by design. While we could do type
>   derivation for the columns and/or coerce to common type, for recursive
>   CTE we chose to keep the derivation strict. There are also corner
>   cases where the type derivation will not be able to arrive at the
>   correct precision/scale/length. This can potentially lead to errors.
>   So our recommendation as you observed is to explicitly type any
>   expression using CAST. -Umachandar, SQL Programmability Team [1]

[1]
    http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/668872/types-dont-match-between-the-anchor-and-the-recursive-part-in-column-columnname-of-recursive-query-cte-name